# Python - How to write data under [ ] in json

Tags: python, json

Need to write data to `[]` in json file formatted like below. Able to update other values but not able to find reference to add the values under Attributes through json module in python.

```
{
    "A": {
        "A1": "Value1",
        "A2": "Value2"
    },
    "B": {
        "B1": [ 
        {
            "B11": "Value3",
            "B12": "Value4",
            "B13": [
                {
                    "Attributes": [
                        "attr1",
                        "attr2",
                        "attr3",
                        "attr4"
                    ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. But `[]` in JSON is a Python list, just like it is in Python. So use `.append()` to add attributes to the list.

Comment: Thanks for response, I am trying to add values under "Attributes". 

I have jsonobject.update to update values for other Keys but for Attributes was not able to as it is showing as List.

I am opening json as file, updating values like this:

with open(filename,"r+") as jsonfile:
header_data =json.load(jsonfile)
a_data = header_data{'A']
a_data.update(A1=Value1, A2=Value2)

Comment: `variable['B']['B1'][0]['B13'][0]['Attributes'].append("attr1")`

Comment: That's not a question, it's a goal. What problem are you having? This is just dictionaries and lists, there's nothing special about adding to the nested list.

Comment: You don't use the `json` module for this. That's just used to convert the dictionary to/from JSON. But once you convert it, it's just normal Python data.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question., how do we access the variable without json module for this. 

variable['B']['B1'][0]['B13'][0]['Attributes'].append("attr1")

Comment: You use `variable = json.load(file)` to load the JSON from a file into the `variable`. Then you just use ordinary Python list and dictionary operations on `variable`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. append("attr1") does add it with single qoutes. I found a way to make them double qoutes.

Comment: Strings don't have single or double quotes, that's just formatting. They'll become double quotes when you use `json.dump()` to write it back to the file.